# Install Numpy in pydev(eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, pydev

I am trying to install a package called 'numpy'. 
i have python setup in eclipse luna with the help of pydev.
how do i install numpy in pydev.

tried putting numpy in site-packages folder. doesnt seem to work

Comment: http://continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, Goto **Windows->Preferences**
Select **PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreters**

Then click on **Manage with pip** button, then you will see a new window like below, you just need to type your package and click Run/Press enter.

[image]

After this, Click Apply and OK, then Right click on Project then click on **PyDev->Remove error markers**.

Hope it works.

Comment: If I do this, I get: Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized

Answer (score 0):

do you have pip installed with your python?
[How to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html)

Then if you have your path variable set you can simply type "pip install numpy" into command line.

Comment: like i said i use eclipse, is there a way to install numpy from eclipse. i have numpy downloaded.

Comment: Mostly, install numpy in your Python install -- by using PIP or any other way you'd like -- the latest versions of PyDev should automatically recognize it after you've done that (no special support is needed on PyDev for that).

Answer (score 0):

download the required version of numpy from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/
and the install directly ,it will run on eclipse automatically

If it does not solve your purpose use Pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is to create a virtualenv `virtualenv ~/venvs/eclipse`, install numpy (`source ~/venv/eclipse/bin/activate;pip install numpy`), then add the virtualenv to eclipse (see https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can be installed after install python in to your pc. 
to install pandas go to command prompt and type "pip install pandas" this command collecting packages related to pandas. After if it asking to upgrade pip or if pip is not recognized by the command prompt use this command:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip.

Comment: What does this have to do with Numpy?