# How to install pandas for running under Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas, installation, pydev

I am new to python, I am able to work with PyDev in Eclipse but not able to with pandas. I tried installing pandas.exe and adding to python interpretor but it is throwing error.

We are using **Eclipse Mars 1 and py 2.7**.

I want to know what is the process to adding any module pandas or numpy ... etc. from eclipse.

Please can some body help in to work with pandas from eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765250/install-numpy-in-pydeveclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657449/python-newbie-importing-numpy-module-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Pandas and numpy in the Python environment you are using.

```
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

Comment: nope, there has to be more to it.. I installed but eclipse not recognizing it.